# Expandable width H2 with BG

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use 3 images (left, repeat and right) as a bg for a 'speech bubble' header, but can't get the middle to repeat to fill the container div.

Here's where it is (the grey bubble with 'hello') http://www.dev.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html

Here's the CSS:

```
.right-nav .speech-left {float:left;background:url(/images/speech-left.png) no-repeat;width:55px;height:47px;}
.right-nav h2.speech-repeat {display:block;float:left;background:url(/images/speech-repeat.png) repeat-x;height:47px;}
.right-nav .speech-right  {float:left;background:url(/images/speech-right.png) no-repeat;width:10px;height:47px;}
```

And the html:

```
<div class="bg clearfix" style="width:100%;">
<div class="speech-left"></div>
<h2 class="speech-repeat">hello</h2>
<div class="speech-right"></div>
</div>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Your code here and the live code are different, the code here works fine, the live code uses inline-block and no float.

Comment: works fine for me, I just used firebug to put the styling as you have on here on your live website and works perfectly fine.  make sure you change it to `block` although in this case `inline-block` will work fine, and make sure you float left.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to float the middle element too:

```
.right-nav h2.speech-repeat {
    background: url(/images/speech-repeat.png) repeat-x;
    height: 47px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: the middle element is floated in the code in the question.  Although his live code is different.

Comment: @JonTaylor, hum, that's right... Anyway, it's was not in the sample when I saw it :P Now it seems to be working. Thx for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest splitting your images differently.  It does work at the moment however since your left image includes the sticky out bit on the bubble at the bottom, the middle part of the bubble cant start till the left part is completely finished.

You could use margins to offset the middle part to make the text display ontop of the left image however I would tend to do it the same way nine patchs work.

[image]

Using this sort of structure obviously uses more images but can produce better results as you can then end up resizing both vertically and horizontally to accomodate any amount of text.

Also just because they use 9 segments doesn't mean you can not use more.  Using more along the bottom section would allow you to have the sticky out bit stay the same scale while the surrounding bottom pieces would expand to fill the area they need to.